# How to split Alfresco workflow files based on file type in Parallel Gateway to direct it into two diffrent path

Tags: workflow, alfresco, activiti

I want to split Alfresco workflow files based on file type(like word and pdf) in Parallel Gateway to direct it into two diffrent path.That is shown as below image.
[Please click to show the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HoEOX.png)

I am using parallel gateway, it is right way or need some other gateway for this type of problem ?
I am new to Alfresco workflow implementation, so please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Alfresco is using activiti workflow engine for the worklfow.Regarding which gateway you should use is depends on your requirement.

Mainly there are 3 gateway used

1. **Parallel Gateway** : It will creating one concurrent execution for each sequence flow.
2. **Exclusive Gateway** : When the execution arrives at this gateway, all outgoing sequence flow are evaluated in the order in which they are defined. The sequence flow which condition evaluates to true is selected for continuing the process.
3. **Inclusive Gateway** : The Inclusive Gateway can be seen as a combination of an exclusive and a parallel gateway. Like an exclusive gateway you can define conditions on outgoing sequence flows and the inclusive gateway will evaluate them. But the main difference is that the inclusive gateway can take more than one sequence flow, like the parallel gateway.

If you are not sure what is gateway in workflow than please refer below link for same.

Detailed Description on activiti gate way : 
 https://www.activiti.org/userguide/#bpmnGateways

Alfresco documentation for gateway  : http://docs.alfresco.com/4.0/concepts/wf-process-def-gateways.html

Comment: I think, Inclusive Gateway will solve my problem but now my concern is how to split workflow files and check thier file type or MIMETYPE so that I could forward it desirable direction ?

Comment: In workflow script whatever code you are writing is alfresco javascript api.You can get mimetype by "document.mimetype".For more details just take a look on https://community.alfresco.com/docs/DOC-5367-javascript-api-cookbook link.and mark it as correct if its correct ;)

Comment: I saw this code ref from other question:                         
ActivitiScriptNode scriptNode = (ActivitiScriptNode)execution.getVariable(WorkflowNotificationUtils.PROP_PACKAGE);
NodeRef packagenode = scriptNode.getNodeRef(); NodeRef docRef= Configuration.serviceRegistry.getNodeService().getChildAssocs(packagenode).get(0).getChildRef();

Comment: Can I get MIMETYPE from docRef variable ? if yes then how ?

Comment: in java you need to do it like this : 
ContentData contentData = (ContentData) nodeService.getProperty(nodeRef, ContentModel.PROP_CONTENT);
String nodeMimeType = contentData.getMimetype();

Comment: Thanks Jayswal,This is very helpful.

Comment: Could you suggest me, how to get ServiceRegistry into TaskListener ?

Comment: @Autowired
 @Qualifier("ServiceRegistry")
 private ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

Comment: //ContentService contentService = serviceRegistry.getContentService();
      NodeService nodeService = serviceRegistry.getNodeService();
      System.out.println("nodeService:"+nodeService);

Answer (score 0):

I have done it with Alfresco jscripting as follows:

```
<activiti:taskListener event="complete" class="org.alfresco.repo.workflow.activiti.tasklistener.ScriptTaskListener">
      <activiti:field name="script">
        <activiti:string><![CDATA[execution.setVariable('bpm_assignee', task.getVariable('bpm_assignee'));
            execution.setVariable('bpm_comment', task.getVariable('bpm_comment'));
            execution.setVariable('wf_manager', person);
            execution.setVariable('bpm_dueDate', task.dueDate);
            execution.setVariable('bpm_priority', task.priority);

            var fileExtention="";

            for (var i = 0; i < bpm_package.children.length; i++) {
                var child = bpm_package.children[i];

                var fileArray = child.properties['cm:name'].split('.'); 
                logger.log("#############FileArray >>"+fileArray);
                fileExtention = fileArray[fileArray.length-1];   
                logger.log("###########FileExtention1  >>"+fileExtention );
                break;
            }

            logger.log("#############FileExtention2  >>"+fileExtention );
            if(fileExtention.indexOf('pdf') != -1){
                execution.setVariable('wf_file_type_pdf', true);
                logger.log("##############PDF found##################");
            } else{
                execution.setVariable('wf_file_type_pdf', false);
                logger.log("##############Word found##################");
            }]]></activiti:string>
      </activiti:field>
    </activiti:taskListener>
```

Now I am able to get file type and it is working fine.
Thanks for support!!!